# C# Gender & Martial Status Filtration (ASP.Net with MVC5)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to filter my table by Gender & Marital Status, I filtered by string successfully but I get the wrong results every time I filter by Gender or Marital Status.

Filtration by Municipality is working fine though.

*I know the code is a mess but I'm new to this amount of coding.

This is the Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace StatsReport.Models
{
    public class Employee
    {
   

      
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "رقم التسجيل")]
        public int Reg_No { get; set; }

        //[RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z'\s]*$")]
        //[Required]
        //[StringLength(30)]
        [Display(Name = "الجنس")]
        public EmployeeGender Sex { get; set; }

        [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3)]
        [Display(Name = "الإسم الأول")]
        public string FName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "اسم الأب")]
        public string SName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "اسم الجد")]
        public string TName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "اللقب")]
        public string LName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "الجنسية")]
        public string Nat { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "اسم الأم")]
        public string MFName { get; set; }
       
        [Display(Name = "مكان الميلاد")]
        public string Birth_Place { get; set; }


        //[Display(Name = "Birth Date")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        //[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "تاريخ الميلاد")]
        public DateTime Birth_Date { get; set; }


        //[RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z'\s]*$")]
        //[Required]
        //[StringLength(30)]
        [Display(Name = "الحالة الإجتماعية")]
        public EmployeeMartialStatus Martial_Status { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "عدد أفراد الأسرة")]
        public int Family_Count { get; set; }

        //[RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z'\s]*$")]
        //[Required]
        //[StringLength(30)]
        [Display(Name = "البلدية")]
        public string Muncp { get; set; }


        //[RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z'\s]*$")]
        //[Required]
        //[StringLength(30)]
        [Display(Name = "المحلة")]
        public string Local { get; set; }

        //[RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z'\s]*$")]
        //[Required]
        //[StringLength(30)]
        [Display(Name = "نوع العقد")]
        public string Contract_Type { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "رقم القرار")]
        public int Res_No { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Display(Name = "تاريخ القرار")]
        public DateTime Res_Year { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Display(Name = "تاريخ توقيع العقد")]
        public DateTime Cont_Sign_Date { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Display(Name = "تاريخ المباشرة")]
        public DateTime Com_Date { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "الرقم الوظيفي")]
        public int Emp_No { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "الرقم المالي")]
        public int Fin_No { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "رقم الضمان الإجتماعي")]
        public int Social_No { get; set; }

        //[RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z'\s]*$")]
        //[Required]
        //[StringLength(30)]
        [Display(Name = "الوظيفة السابقة")]
        public string Prev_Job { get; set; }


        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Display(Name = "تاريخ تعيين الوظيفة السابقة")]
        public DateTime Prev_Job_Date { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<TeacherDiploma> Diplomas { get; set; }
    }
    public enum EmployeeGender
    {
        ذكر,
        أنثى
    }
    public enum EmployeeMartialStatus
    {
        متزوج,
        أعزب
    }
}
```

And This is the controller code:

```
namespace StatsReport.Controllers
{
    public class EmployeeController : Controller
    {
        private StatsReportContext db = new StatsReportContext();

        // GET: Employee
        public ActionResult Index(string employeeSex, string employeeMStatus, string employeeMuncp, string searchString)
        {
            // GET: Employee/ By Sex
            var SexLst = new List<EmployeeGender>();
            var SexQry = from d in db.Staff
                         orderby d.Sex
                         select d.Sex;
            SexLst.AddRange(SexQry.Distinct());
            ViewBag.employeeSex = new SelectList(SexLst);

            // GET: Employee/ By Martial Status
            var MStatusLst = new List<EmployeeMartialStatus>();
            var MStatusQry = from d in db.Staff
                             orderby d.Martial_Status
                             select d.Martial_Status;
            MStatusLst.AddRange((IEnumerable<EmployeeMartialStatus>)MStatusQry.Distinct());
            ViewBag.employeeMStatus = new SelectList(MStatusLst);

            // GET: Trainer/ By Muncipality
            var MuncLst = new List<string>();
            var MuncQry = from d in db.Staff
                          orderby d.Muncp
                          select d.Muncp;
            MuncLst.AddRange(MuncQry.Distinct());
            ViewBag.employeeMuncp = new SelectList(MuncLst);

            var employee = from m in db.Staff
                          select m;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                employee = employee.Where(s => s.FName.Contains(searchString));
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(employeeSex))
            {

                employee = employee.Where(x => x.Sex == EmployeeGender.ذكر);
            }
            else 
            {
                employee = employee.Where(x => x.Sex == EmployeeGender.أنثى);
            }
            

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(employeeMStatus))
            {
                employee = employee.Where(x => x.Martial_Status == EmployeeMartialStatus.أعزب);
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(employeeMuncp))
            {
                employee = employee.Where(x => x.Muncp == employeeMuncp);
            }
            return View(employee);
```

I came closer to the point when I dealt with Sex as an Integer as the following, but the results aren't correct, I have 3 choices in the dropdown list: All(Default) - Male - Female, when I choose All I get Female, when I choose Male I got Male - When I choose Female I got Male again?

```
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(employeeSex))
        {
            employee = employee.Where(x => x.Sex != 0);
          

        }
       
        else 
        {
            employee = employee.Where(x => x.Sex == 0);

        };
```

It worked!, but I have (All - Male - Female) in the dropdown list, when I choose all it only view Male not Male & Female!, I only need to fix this and it's solved.

```
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(employeeSex) && Enum.TryParse<EmployeeGender>(employeeSex, out var ذكر))
            {
                employee = employee.Where(x => x.Sex == ذكر);
                
            }
```

Comment: So you mean `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(employeeSex) && Enum.TryParse<EmployeeGender>(employeeSex, out var value)) employee = employee.Where(x => x.Sex == value);` ?

Comment: I'm getting closer, I have 3 choices in the dropdown list of filtration: When I choose (All) I get only Male - when I choose (Male) I get Female and when I choose Female I get Female, something still wrong with my code and I couldn't figure it out yet.

Comment: Also pls note that you are  not  checking selected  employee gender option  in the if condition.  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(employeeSex)) . You are just checking user input is null or empty.

Comment: Welcome @Aym90B, I'm fairly sure that `StatsReportContext` is disposable and so you need to dispose it, or inject it and let the DI container take care of the lifetime.  Also please use methods for your database actions, and hopefully in your real code they are not in your controller. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's completely solved:

1- Gender:

```
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(employeeSex) && Enum.TryParse<EmployeeGender>(employeeSex, out var ذكر))
            {
                foreach (int i in Enum.GetValues(typeof(EmployeeGender)))
                {
                    employeeSex=($" {i}");
                }
                employee = employee.Where(x => x.Sex == ذكر);
                
            }
```

2- Martial Status:

```
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(employeeMStatus) && Enum.TryParse<EmployeeMartialStatus>(employeeMStatus, out var أعزب))
            {
                foreach (int i in Enum.GetValues(typeof(EmployeeMartialStatus)))
                {
                    employeeMStatus = ($" {i}");
                }
                employee = employee.Where(x => x.Martial_Status == أعزب);

            }
```

Comment: How can an employee have multiple genders? You can just do `Enum.GetValues<EmployeeGender>()` or `Enum.GetNames<EmployeeGender>()`? Also you should use methods `var genders = GetGenders()` And then use that.